# Laravel date format pivot table

Tags: php, date, laravel, format

I have a model `Entry` which has a many-to-many relationship with the model `Product`. This relationship has a pivot table (`entry_product`) with a `valid_to` attribute.

To the database this `valid_to` attribute is a timestamp, this is OK. But I would like to format it, before receiving it as a JSON response.

The function responsible for the relationship is the following:

```
public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'entry_products')->withPivot(['quantity', 'price', 'valid_to']);
    }
```

Do I have to create a new Model, to support this operation? Is there a way to format all those dates, without looping through the fetched data, before sending it as a JSON response?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use a model presenter. Model Presenters present the model data in the desired format that we specify.

1. I recommend you to use [laravel-auto-presenter](https://github.com/laravel-auto-presenter/laravel-auto-presenter). The documentation is self-explanatory. Please go thru it and if you face any difficulties post it here.

   Fortunately, the example given in the documentation uses timestamp.
2. You can use [Laravel5-json](https://github.com/nilportugues/laravel5-json) package if you want to send response directly.
3. You can override `toJson` method to return the model as you wish. It is lot more independent of external packages and cleaner.